# How to rename Service created by @Angular/cli using command

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I created a service `team-secret.service` using command `n g s team-secret`
But now I want to rename it `team.service` using command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are expecting the cli to do that for you then the answer is that it will not. As far as renaming any references in your code goes, then choose a favorite method and there are likely plugins for IDE/Editor of choice to do so. On the upside, unless you used the `-m` option when generating the service, there is no reference anywhere in your code anyway. So just rename the files.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for your response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Angular CLI doesn't support the feature of renaming or refactoring code.
You can achieve such functionality with help of some IDE's

You can use Microsoft Visual studio code to achieve this with the help of a plugin

More details can be found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts)

you can follow the same steps described here

[How to rename a component in Angular CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411036/how-to-rename-a-component-in-angular-cli/47920931#47920931)